# Java: pass an arraylist of doubly-linked list as a parameter

Tags: java, arraylist, parameter-passing, doubly-linked-list

Gurus, I have difficulty to pass an arraylist of doubly-linked list as a parameter.

I need to represent square matrices in data structure that involves linked-list. I decided to use an arraylist of doubly-linked list. Matrices information read from a text file, is stored in:

```
ArrayList<DoubleLinkedList<Integer>> dLLArrayList
```

After reads in the first input, dllArryList has content `"[[5]]"`

I try to create a new matrix object by calling the constructor from self-defined Matrix class:

```
Matrix mx1 = new Matrix (dimension, dLLArrayList);
```

** dimension is just an int variable that store the size of the matrix, say 1 for a 1 by 1 matrix, as indicated on the input text file.

However, as I try to print out the matrix content inside the Matrix class, it returns `"[[]]":`

```
System.out.println (this.getMatrixArrayList());
```

Here is the set method inside the matrix class that suppose to set ArrayList elements of a Matrix object:

```
public void setMatrixArrayList(ArrayList<DoubleLinkedList<Integer>> matrixArrayList) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixArrayList.size(); i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixArrayList.get(i).size(); j ++) {
            this.rowItemList.add(matrixArrayList.get(i).get(j));
        }
        this.matrixArrayList.add(this.rowItemList);
        this.rowItemList.clear();
    }
}
```

Any reason this won't work? Suggestions, Comments?

Comment: Please properly format your code...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up veer, I just corrected code format. This is my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: It maybe other part of my program that is not quite working. I will keep this posted up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you clear the rowItemList. When you add the rowItemList to the arraylist you just put the reference there. So when you clear it later the linkedlist just added inside the arraylist is also cleared. You need to clone the rowItemList when you add it in the outer list.

```
public void setMatrixArrayList(ArrayList<DoubleLinkedList<Integer>> matrixArrayList) {
for(int i = 0; i < matrixArrayList.size(); i ++){
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixArrayList.get(0).size(); j ++) {
        this.rowItemList.add(matrixArrayList.get(0).get(j));
    }
    this.matrixArrayList.add(this.rowItemList.clone());
    this.rowItemList.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Masood_mj. You made a good point. However, it seems like clone() is not a method that could be used directly. I will try to add an override method to my DoubleLinkedList class and see if that will do the trick.

Comment: That's right I forgot that you have implemented DoubleLinkedList class yourself. You may want to see the LinkedList clone implementation to get some idea

Comment: @HangYu: the way you use `rowItemList` doesn't make sense. Why have a list instance variable that is cleared at the end of every loop in one of the functions? Perhaps you want a local variable defined inside the loop instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @newacct . I wanted to "re-use" the `rowItemList` variable to store a row of matrix integers. Let me try to re-iterate your suggestion: define a local `rowList` inside the inner for loop, remove the use the `.clone()` method on the outter loop and remove `this.rowItemList.clear()`.

My question is: when i increments from 0 to 1 (I have updated the original post), what will the local `rowlist` stores? A list of integers from row 2 of the matrix, or a list of integers from row2 plus a list of integers from row 1.

Comment: @HangYu: Well you would also need to initialize the `rowList` to a new  empty list at the beginning of every loop. Since the variable is scoped inside the loop, in every iteration of the loop it's like a new, separate local variable, which you have to initialize before using. Actually, you could apply this to what you were doing before -- setting `rowItemList` to a new empty list at the beginning of each loop would also solve your problem; but it is good practice to only declare a variable in the smallest scope needed.

Comment: @HangYu: You talk about "re-using" `rowItemList`. It is unnecessary to keep a variable around for "re-using"; if you put it inside the loop, the compiler probably uses the same memory location for it anyway, since the uses of it do not overlap. But you are probably confusing objects and references. `rowItemList` is a reference (pointer to an object). A reference only takes a few bytes of memory. You are probably thinking about "re-using" objects instead. But your exercise fundamentally requires you to create a new object per iteration, whether you are cloning, or initializing to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `i` anywhere.

I suspect you want:

```
for (int j = 0; j < matrixArrayList.get(i).size(); j ++) {
        this.rowItemList.add(matrixArrayList.get(i).get(j));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments John. You have a good point, I updated the code. However, no dice. I will update post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList or LinkedList is just an array of other linked lists

So i'm assuming

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList> methodTest(ArrayList<ArrayList> doubleList) {}
```

would work

Comment: You are right Dmor574. In my opinion the difficulty is that you can't use: "this.matrixArrayList = matrixArrayList;" in the set method.

For a lack of knowledge, I believe collection objects behaves differently from a simple object.

Comment: well the problem with passing them in is that it is pass by reference. Which is why I almost always create class variables that hold array lists. If I was you, i'd create a seperate class that manages the double arraylist